# Magento Wysiwyg editor issue when try insert an image (probably js incompability)

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, wysiwyg

I am having an issue while try to add an image using the **Wysiwyg editor** in Magento. The error I get is that the image upload tool displays with code (tags) on it and the upload or browse icon do not appears at all.

[image: Magento image upload tool]

I am thinking it could be caused by a js compatibility issue. As I'm not a js developer, how could I check the issue this tool is showing up?

I am also thinking in replacing my wysiwyg js files with the original ones, but when I download the original magento installation files I don't see any js folder at all.

I need to solve this issue. Help much appreciated. Thank you in advance.
Regards - Yolanda

Answer (score 0):

I would try to re-upload the magento core files, incase anything has become corrupted, i've had this a couple of times when transferring files.

I believe the files associated with the uploader & media parts of magento would be:

```
\app\code\core\Mage\Uploader
\app\code\core\Mage\Media
```